# How do I track hotlinking of images and iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed, analytics

I give out an embed html code so others can post parts of my website as an iframe. I want to be able to track who has my embed code posted. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you generate the embed-able code, give each person a new GUID.

Embed the GUID inside the embed-able code so that the GUID is passed to your content. You can then log each hit from each GUID for tracking.

**UPDATE**

Since you're going to be spreading the embed code virally, I would suggest checking the HTTP_REFERER field in the HTTP header. It should (I believe) contain the URL of the page loading your content.

Comment: The embed code is expected to be passed around virally. I can't trust a unique id will be assigned or even created in the first place. I was hoping for something that can "sense" where the hotlink is coming from.